# Xamarin: Check if an event exists before adding it to the calendar in android

Tags: c#, xamarin, calendar, xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin forms to add an event to the native calendar of android platform. I have made dependency service to add an event across platforms. I am able to add an event, but before adding any event, I want to apply a check to restrict if any event of same unique identifier exists then it should not allow to add that event.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466963/check-if-the-event-exists-before-adding-it-to-the-android-calender) but didn't worked, as I could not found any `Cursor` class in xamarin on android platform.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if the event exists before adding it to the Android calender](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466963/check-if-the-event-exists-before-adding-it-to-the-android-calender)

Comment: @hankide : I tried that but didn't worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On **Android**, you need to do the following to fetch data from calendar using the new APIs.

You need the permission `android.permisson.READ_CALENDAR`

Interact with calendar data by using the `CalendarContract` class. This class provides a data model that applications can use when they interact with the calendar provider.

To enumerate the calendars that have been registered in the calendar app. To do this, we can call the [ManagedQuery](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.ManagedQuery/p/Android.Net.Uri/System.String%5B%5D/System.String/System.String%5B%5D/System.String/) method. At a minimum, we’ll need to specify the content Uri for calendars and the columns we want to return; this column specification is known as a projection. Calling `ManagedQuery` allows us to query a content provider for data, such as the calendar provider, and returns a **Cursor** with the results of the query.

```
var calendarsUri = CalendarContract.Calendars.ContentUri;
```

Specifying the projection :

```
string[] calendarsProjection = {
    CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.Id,
    CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.CalendarDisplayName,
    CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.AccountName,
   , CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title
   , CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart
   , CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend
};
```

You can pass in more parameters instead of null. Look at other parameters available [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Provider.CalendarContract+Events+InterfaceConsts/).

```
var cursor = ManagedQuery (calendarsUri, calendarsProjection, null, null, null);
```

Managed query is deprecated, and it's better you use `ContentResolver`.

```
var cursor = context.ContentResolver.Query(calendarsUri, calendarsProjection, null, null, null);
```

with date filter :

```
var selection = "((dtstart <= ?) AND (dtend >= ?))";
var selectionArgs = new string[] { startString, endString };
Forms.Context.ApplicationContext.ContentResolver.Query(calendarsUri, calendarsProjection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
```

or

```
var ctx = Forms.Context;
var cursor = ctx.ApplicationContext.ContentResolver.Query(calendarsUri, calendarsProjection, null, null, null);
```

The parameters to [Query](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Provider.CalendarContract+Instances.Query/p/Android.Content.ContentResolver/System.String%5B%5D/System.Int64/System.Int64/) are :

- cr - The ContentResolver to use for the query
- projection - The columns to return
- begin -The start of the time range to query in UTC millis since epoch
- end - The end of the time range to query in UTC millis since epoch

The whole tutorial and step by step explanation is provided [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/calendar/).
Read about `ContentResolver` [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/38160/how-can-i-use-managedquery-in-a-dependencyservice-implementation).

For **iOS**, you have to use **EventKit**.

To retrieve an event by it’s ID, use the `EventFromIdentifier` method on the `EventStore` and pass it the `EventIdentifier` that was pulled from the event:

```
var mySavedEvent = App.Current.EventStore.EventFromIdentifier (newEvent.EventIdentifier);
```

To search for calendar events, you must create an `NSPredicate` object via the `PredicateForEvents` method on the `EventStore`. An `NSPredicate` is a query data object that iOS uses to locate matches:

```
NSPredicate query = App.Current.EventStore.PredicateForEvents (startDate, endDate, null);
```

*The third parameter is calendars to query, to use all calendars, pass null.*

Once the NSPredicate is created, use the EventsMatching method on the EventStore, execute the query :

```
EKCalendarItem[] events = App.Current.EventStore.EventsMatching (query);
```

The full tutorials is available [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_event_kit/) and for sample look [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/Calendars/).

Comment: I am getting error on ManagedQuery method. Is there any namespace for it.

Comment: I used this: =>   var eventsUri = CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri;

            string[] eventsProjection = {
                        CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title,
                        CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend,
                        CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart,
                    };

            var cursor = ctx.ApplicationContext.ContentResolver.Query(eventsUri, eventsProjection, String.Format("calendar_id={0}", 1), null, "dtstart ASC");  How to intertate cursor to check any event exist in particular dtstart and dtend

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi - Check the updated answer with explanation on paramters. Pass epoch datetime as start and end date to Query.

Comment: I did this : var ctx = Forms.Context;
            var cursor = ctx.ApplicationContext.ContentResolver.Query(calendarsUri, calendarsProjection, dtStart.Millisecond.ToString(), dtEnd.Millisecond.ToString());  but is giving error ("No overloaded Query Takes 4 Argument ")

Comment: i have added the sample, also check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477859/how-to-query-android-calendar-events-for-specific-date-range

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121890/discussion-between-himanshu-dwivedi-and-rohit).